# What is the difference between Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: ubuntu

What is the difference between Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

I'm doing research on Ubuntu. 
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

14.04 was released in April 2014. It receives security updates until April 2019

16.04 was released in April 2016. It contains newer versions of the software and receives security updates until April 2021.

16.04 is just a newer version, I wouldn't recommend setting up new systems with 14.04. The current LTS version is 18.04.

LTS versions receive updates for 5 years, non-LTS versions only for 18 months.

See the [release cycle documentation](https://www.ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle) for details.